# Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape multiple pages using grequests and beautifulsoup. I am able to scrape one single page but when I change it to iterate over multiple pages I am getting the above error listed in the title.
CODE:

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

_city = input('Enter the name of the City and State, example format(miami-fl): ')
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0'}

def get_urls():
    urls = []
    for x in range(1,2):
        urls.append(f'https://www.apartments.com/miami-fl/{x}/')
    return urls

def get_data(urls):
    reqs = [grequests.get(link) for link in urls]
    resp = grequests.map(reqs)
    return resp
    

def parse(resp):
    apartments = []
    for r in resp:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        results = soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'mortar-wrapper'})
        for item in results:
            apartment = {
                'Property_name': item.find('span', {'class': 'js-placardTitle title'}).text,
                'Unit_name': item.find(''),
                'Formatted_address': item.find('div', {'class': 'property-address js-url'}).text,
                'City&State': _city,
                'Bedrooms': item.find('div', {'class': 'bed-range'}).text,
                'Price_Range': item.find('div', {'class': 'price-range'}).text,
                'Availability': item.find('div', {'class': 'availability'}).text,
                'Property_Amenities': item.find('div', {'class': 'property-amenities'}).text.strip(),
                'Phone_Number': item.find('a', {'class': 'phone-link js-phone'}).attrs['href'],
            }
            apartments.append(apartment)
            print(apartments)
    return apartments

#def output(apartments):
    aptdf = pd.DataFrame(apartments)
    aptdf.to_csv('apts.csv', index=False)
    print('Saved to CSV')
    return    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls = get_urls()
    resp = get_data(urls)
    df = pd.DataFrame(parse(resp))
    df.to_csv('apts.csv', index=False)
    #output(apartments)```
    edited code to correct format but still wont run or debug
````

Comment: Did you check the data you have in ```resp```?

Comment: I am getting None back, over and over because of the loop so grequests isn't picking up the data it needs

Comment: Which one?You have one in ```get_data``` and one in ```parse```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using `grerequests` instead of `requests` module?

Comment: See the responses you receive in ```resp``` you might have ```None``` there.

Comment: The one in get_data: I am using grequests for storing multiple responses, I am new to grequests but thought this was how it was used; to parse multiple responses

Comment: What is the value of ```reqs``` in ```get_data```

Comment: The value of reqs in get_data is ([<grequests.AsyncRequest object at 0x7f6c988d1d30>])